# Singly linked list implementation in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I have implemented a Singly linked list. It works well. But if you think something needs to be improved, say it. This code was tested in Python 3.7.4.

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.nextNode = None

class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    # O(1) !!!  
    def insertStart(self, data):

        self.size = self.size + 1
        newNode = Node(data)

        if not self.head:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            newNode.nextNode = self.head
            self.head = newNode

    def remove(self, data):

        if self.head is None:
            return

        self.size = self.size - 1

        currentNode = self.head
        previousNode = None

        while currentNode.data != data:
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode

        if previousNode is None:
            self.head = currentNode.nextNode
        else:
            previousNode.nextNode = currentNode.nextNode            

    # O(1)  
    def size1(self):
        return self.size


    # O(N)
    def insertEnd(self, data):

        self.size = self.size + 1
        newNode = Node(data)
        actualNode = self.head

        while actualNode.nextNode is not None:
            actualNode = actualNode.nextNode

        actualNode.nextNode = newNode

    def traverseList(self):

        actualNode = self.head

        while actualNode is not None:
            print(actualNode.data)
            actualNode = actualNode.nextNode
```

Comment: You added the [tag:unit-testing] tag, but I cannot see any unit tests in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing several important things for this code:

### Type Annotations

Python 3.7 supports type annotations. Especially for a container class like this, you should fully use them.

### Initializer parameters

Python containers generally all provide builder methods or class initializer functions that take other containers and use their contents. Consider:

- [`dict(`*iterable,*`**kwarg)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)
- [`list(`*iterable*`)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)
- [`set(`*iterable*`)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)
- [`str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)
- [`tuple(`*iterable*`)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)

If you're writing a Python container, you need to conform to expectations. I expect to be able to initialize the container when I create it.

### Protocols & Magic methods

Python has a well-established set of *protocols* for implementing containers. You just have to decide what kind of container you're writing.

I would suggest that a singly-linked list is an [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), a [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range), a [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) and possibly a [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) type.

Comment: The _type annotations_ comment is certainly true, but a more direct reference to documentation is important for the uninitiated, if not an example applied to the code.